# Asymptotic behavior of $(1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5 + \cdots + (n-1)/n ) \times n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am interested in the following questions:

given:

$$G(n) = \left(\frac12 + \frac23 + \frac34 + \frac45 + \cdots +  \frac{n-1}n\right)n$$

1. what is a $F(n)$ which could be an upper bound (clearly as tight as possible) for $G(n)$ for $n$ arbitrarily large ?
2. Does the series: $$\frac12 + \frac23 + \frac34 + \frac45 + \cdots +  \frac{n-1}n$$ have a "name" and a sum (any reference)?

Comment: This question most likely does not belong here, but should be migrated to math.SE. This site is specifically about software _Mathematica_, even though _Mathematica_ can do symbolic mathematics. If you have access to _Mathematica_, you can just type your query in and it will provide you with the answer. If you do not have access to [_Mathematica_](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica), you could try using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) which is built using _Mathematica_ and is quite capable of evaluating such a simple sum as yours.

Answer (score 9):

Let $$F(n) = \left(\dfrac{2-1}{2} + \dfrac{3-1}{3} + \dfrac{4-1}{4} + \cdots + \dfrac{n-1}{n} \right) $$ we then have that
$$F(n) = \left(1 - \dfrac12 + 1 - \dfrac13 + 1 - \dfrac14 + \cdots + 1 - \dfrac1n \right) = (n-1) - \left( \dfrac12 + \dfrac13 + \cdots + \dfrac1n \right)$$
Now note that $$-\left( \dfrac12 + \dfrac13 + \cdots + \dfrac1n \right) = 1 - H_n = 1 - \left(\log(n) + \gamma + \dfrac1{2n} - \dfrac1{12n^3} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^5) \right)$$
Hence, $$F(n) = n - \left(\log(n) + \gamma + \dfrac1{2n} - \dfrac1{12n^3} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^5) \right)$$
$$nF(n) = n^2 - n \log n  -\gamma n - \dfrac12 + \dfrac1{12n^2} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^4)$$
You could make use of the fact that $$H_n = \log (n) + \gamma - \dfrac{\zeta(0)}n +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\zeta(-k)}{n^{k+1}}$$ to get better approximations/bounds.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12+\frac23+\frac34+\frac45+\ldots+\frac{n-1}n&=n-1-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k\\
&=n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&=n-H_n\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), so $$G(n)=n^2-nH_n\;.$$

There are good approximations of $H_n$ by relatively nice functions:

$$H_n\sim\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}\;,$$

for instance, and the approximation can be improved by taking more terms of the series

$$H_n\sim\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{B_{2k}}{2kn^{2k}}\;,$$

where the numbers $B_k$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 3):

Your expression in the parentheses is $(n-1)-\left(\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ which is asymptotically related to $n-\ln n$. So in total you have something like $n^2-n \ln n. $Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding your second question**: Just type "sum 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5 + 5/6 + ... + (n - 1)/n" or something similar in WolframAlpha. According to WolframAlpha this sum does not have a name but is equal to $n - {H_n}$ where ${H_n}$ is the $n$-th harmonic number. Source: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

Comment: Great idea, it also gives 2nd interpretation as `n-polygamma(0, n+1)-gamma`

Comment: BTW, [**this is the URL**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F2+%2B+2%2F3+%2B+3%2F4+%2B+4%2F5+%2B+5%2F6+%2B+...+%2B+%28n+-+1%29%2Fn)